# Can I connect to Tarantool with mysql or psql console?

Tags: tarantool

I found that I can do SQL requests but only inside Tarantool.

Can I somehow connect to Tarantool like in MySQL shell or Postgres shell?

```
mysql -u admin -h localhost -P 3301
# or
psql ...
```

Or how to configure other programs that understand only MySQL or Postgres connections to use Tarantool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use either `mysql` or `psql` console commands to connect to Tarantool, because the communication protocol is different for each server. For the same reason, for example, you cannot connect to Posgres using the `mysql` utility. However, nothing prevents you from using [tarantoolctl](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/2.3/reference/tarantoolctl/) to perform SQL requests to Tarantool. Once attached to an instance (either with `tarantoolctl enter my_instance` or `tarantoolctl connect <uri>`), you can switch the default language from Lua to SQL:

```
\set language sql
\set delimiter ;
```

After that you will be able to execute SQL statements directly in the console.

For the record, it's also possible to execute SQL using [Lua functions](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/2.3/reference/reference_lua/box_sql/#lua-function.box.execute), but this may seem less convenient:

```
box.execute([[ SELECT 1, 2, 3 ]])
```